# SQL Get list of record combinations from related key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, combinations

I need to get a list of possible combinations of a MIX field from a table structure (which, I will note, is itself derived from several select statements) that looks like the following:

```
#:| [key1],  [key2],  [Key3],  [MIX]
   ------------------------------------------
1 |  001      0        20       m1
2 |  001      0        20       c1
3 |  001      0        20       a1
4 |  002      0        30       m1
5 |  002      0        30       c1
6 |  002      1        10       m1
7 |  002      1        10       c1
8 |  002      1        10       a1
9 |  002      1        40       m1
10|  002      1        40       c2
```

where the list of resulting distinct combinations of MIX records by key fields would be:

```
1| m1 c1 a1
2| m1 c1
3| m1 c2
```

I don't care to much what the output format looks like at this point, but I will later be using it to go back and certain records.

I already have the script to get the table above, but I'm scrathing my head as to how to get this.

Note: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio (so T-SQL is all fair game). I wouldn't mind doing this analysis in vba either, but I'm sure their's a simpler way to do it in SQL that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: Why couldn't you have, for example, `a1 c2`?

Comment: Because in the example table, the combinations are decided by sets of matched keys. c2 only shows up the [002, 1, 40] key set, with m1, so that combination comes out as m1 c1 (although the order doesn't really matter, just that they are in the same keyset).


Other than that, there is no fundamental rule that an a# and c# combination cannot exist.

Comment: This is indeed not too difficult, provided the DBMS features a windows group concat function such as Oracle#s `LISTAGG`. Here is an example in Oracle SQL, maybe you or someone else can translate it to T-SQL: http://rextester.com/BKADB27624

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may notice the Top 1000 in NEWMIX.  This was to keep what appears to be your desired sequence

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
    Select Distinct 
           [Key] = concat(key1,key2,key3)
          ,mix 
    from YourTable
)
Select Distinct
       NewMix = Stuff((Select ' ' +mix From (Select Top 1000 Mix from cte Where [Key]=A.[Key] Order by Mix Desc) S For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
 From cte A
```

**Returns**

```
NewMix
m1 c1
m1 c1 a1
m1 c2
```

> **EDIT - If the sequence is not important**

```
NewMix = Stuff((Select ' ' +mix From cte Where [Key]=A.[Key] For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
```